# How do I remove these alternating bands on an SSRS chart

Tags: charts, reporting-services

Simple question. But I just can't seem to find the answer.

I've tried setting background patterns and styles to none.

---

### [image]

It must be me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found it.

You click in the `Axis Properties` and select `Axis Options` and then remove the check for `Use Interlace Colour`

[image]

et voilà!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using 2008 since it's not mentioned - let me know if I need to update this.

Right click on the **Axis** and make sure `Show Major Gridlines` is unchecked:

[image]

**Edit after comment:**

Another way you can have bands in charts is through **Striplines**. Do you have anything set up under this property for your **Axis**?

[image]

Remove any that exist in the **Collection**.

Comment: Nope. It removed the lines but not the pattern.

Comment: Does your chart have different shading in the background? Sorry, it's very light in the screenshot (at least on my screen). If that's the case I've edited the question for something to look at in this case.

Comment: I'll check the striplines, but I think I've found it elsewhere. See below

Comment: Good job, looks like you've sorted it yourself; I may as well leave my answer just in case someone else stumbles on this question.